# Place newline before quotes and upper using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file that I'm trying to sort into a CSV. The file looks like

```
"ANIMAL HARNESS"," 2 gp"," Weight 2 lbs.","This leather or hemp     harness allows a holder to restrain and control a domesticated animal. A harness is standard equipment for anyone trying to teach an animal tricks with the Handle Animal skill. Ready-made harnesses are available in most markets for common domesticated animals such as cats, dogs, horses, and oxen, but harnesses can be made for nearly any creature.","AXE BEAK (COMBAT TRAINED)"," 1,500 gp"," Weight 500 lbs.","These Large avian predators are sometimes used as hunting animals but are prized as mounts."
```

I need to place a new line "\n" in front of "ANIMAL HARNESS" and "AXE BEAK"

```
grep -E '"\b[[:upper:]]+\b'
```

or

```
grep -E '"\b[[A-Z][A-Z]+\b'
```

matches the string. But I cannot come up with the matching `sed` statement that will place the new line character correctly.

Comment: Which variant of `sed` are you using?  GNU `sed`?  It matters because there are differences between implementations in how you access extended regular expressions.  Also, there's already a newline (or start of file) before `"ANIMAL HARNESS"`; are you sure you want another?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ...and how you insert a newline ;)

Comment: I'm using GNU sed version 4.2.2

Comment: Oh and the newline in front of ANIMAL HARNESS is fine either way. I can edit it out, but the file is huge with many newlines needed. Editing one line is fine, editing hundreds is much easier with sed. (At least in theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your one line of text in a file `data`, using GNU `sed`:

```
$ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -r 's/"[A-Z]{2,}/\n&/g' data

"ANIMAL HARNESS"," 2 gp"," Weight 2 lbs.","This leather or hemp     harness allows a holder to restrain and control a domesticated animal. A harness is standard equipment for anyone trying to teach an animal tricks with the Handle Animal skill. Ready-made harnesses are available in most markets for common domesticated animals such as cats, dogs, horses, and oxen, but harnesses can be made for nearly any creature.",
"AXE BEAK (COMBAT TRAINED)"," 1,500 gp"," Weight 500 lbs.","These Large avian predators are sometimes used as hunting animals but are prized as mounts."   
$
```

The regex looks for a double quote and two or more capital letters, and inserts a newline before that, globally on the line.

Using BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`:

```
$ /usr/bin/sed -E 's/"[A-Z ()]*"/\
&/g' data

"ANIMAL HARNESS"," 2 gp"," Weight 2 lbs.","This leather or hemp     harness allows a holder to restrain and control a domesticated animal. A harness is standard equipment for anyone trying to teach an animal tricks with the Handle Animal skill. Ready-made harnesses are available in most markets for common domesticated animals such as cats, dogs, horses, and oxen, but harnesses can be made for nearly any creature.",
"AXE BEAK (COMBAT TRAINED)"," 1,500 gp"," Weight 500 lbs.","These Large avian predators are sometimes used as hunting animals but are prized as mounts."   
$
```

Note that use of `-E` vs `-r`, and the use of backslash-newline instead of backslash-n for the replacement text — that's the difference alluded to by [Benjamin W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205154/place-newline-before-quotes-and-upper-using-sed#comment60043725_36205154).  The pattern is slightly different; it looks for all caps, spaces and parentheses between a pair of double quotes.  That's fussier and more prone to failure because you have `"AXE (2 BLADED)"` or something.  It can be revised to `'s/"[A-Z]{2,}/…/'` as with GNU `sed`, but the replacement needs the backslash-newline still.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That makes a lot of sense and more along the lines of what I was trying.